# Inconsistencies in Firebase Firestore API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can someone enlighten me on why there are are such unnecessary inconsistencies in the firestore api in the different language SDKs. Frequently, firebase developers refer to the importance of keeping the API consistent across platforms, so it seems strange to have allowed this to happen.

In the Python, Java, Android, and Swift firestore sdks, in order to reference a document, the function needed is titled `document`, but in Go, Web, and Node it is titled `doc`.

```
var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');
```

vs

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
```

Comment: I noticed this too and I assume the reason it's `doc()` in Javascript is to avoid confusion with the HTML DOM `document` keyword, but I'm not sure why `doc()` was chosen in Go and Node as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In designing APIs we try to balance adhering to platform idioms against being consistent across platforms. So this method naming was actually an intentional deviation. JavaScript and Go both commonly use short, concise method names, whereas e.g. Obj-C has long, verbose method names (so the same method is called collectionWithPath: in Obj-C). There should generally be a 1-1 correspondence between methods across platforms, but the actual naming does differ. Sorry if it tripped you up!

Comment: Only caused a small stumble :) Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: imho though it was the wrong design choice, especially considering the cloud functions firestore trigger requires specifying .document